# Jenkins build base don parameter value

Tags: jenkins

Say my `Jenkinsfile` is like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters {
        string(name: 'flag', defaultValue: 'stop', description: 'How should I greet the world?')
    }
    stages {
    stage('Example') {
            steps {
                checkout scm
                sh "echo \"Current Branch: ${env.BRANCH_NAME}.... \""
        sh 
           if [[ $(params.flag) == "run" ]]; then 
               echo "something"
           fi
```

This is failing. It is not able to read `$(params.flag)` inside steps. How can I do this?? I am using `multibranch pipeline` job type.

Answer (score 1):

It's like this (i think it was mostly the multi-line `sh` syntax that was off):

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'docker' }
    parameters {
        string(name: 'flag', defaultValue: 'stop', description: 'How should I greet the world?')
    }
    stages {
        stage('Example') {
            steps {
                checkout scm
                sh "echo \"Current Branch: ${env.BRANCH_NAME}.... \""
                sh """
                    if [[ "${params.flag}" == "run" ]]; then
                        echo "something"
                    fi
                """
            }
        }
    }
}
```